# How can I wrap the int[] into an object and implement equals()?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, contains

I am trying to see how can I test if an element, with the *same value* as one already inside my `Stack`, is in fact in my stack.

ex.

```java
int aa[] = {5,1};
int bb[] = {3,4};
int cc[] = {3,4};

Stack stack = new Stack();

stack.push(aa);
stack.push(bb);

System.out.println(stack.contains(cc));
>>>false
```

If I understand correctly this is `false` because the `int[]` objects are pointers, and becuase they are pointing at two different arrays, they are considered unequal. ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723813/8315879))

I'm trying to wrap the `int[]` into an object and implement `equals` and `hashCode`, as was done in the answer to the other question but I'm getting a `Cannot resolve symbol 'myArray'` on `o.myArray.length != myArray.length` and `int i = 0; i < o.myArray.length; i++`. I also don't undertand why I need / where `hashCode()` is used.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better solution?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IntArray {

    public int[] myArray;

    public IntArray () {
        myArray = new int[0];
    }

    public IntArray (int[] array) {
        myArray = array;
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return myArray;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(myArray);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (!(o instanceof IntArray))
            return false;

        if (o.myArray.length != myArray.length)
            return false;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < o.myArray.length; i++) {
                if (myArray[i] != myArray[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to cast `o` to `IntArray`. But why not use `Arrays.equals()`?

Comment: like `if (Arrays.equals(o.myArray, myArray))` ? I'm sorry I don't understand, how do I  cast `o` to `IntArray`

Comment: I think the real question here is this: are you always testing pairs, and what kind of values do you want in that `Stack`? Paris of int(s), or just int(s)? Basically, if `aa` was `{1, 3}` and `bb` was `{4, 5}` should it match `{3, 4}`?

Comment: Like `return o instanceof IntArray && Arrays.equals(((IntArray)o).myArray, this.myArray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall leave the question of a better way of doing this and explain what you are being told.

`o` is always of type `Object` in the `equals` method. The `Object` class does not have a `myArray` field - hence the error. That you checked `o`'s an instance of `IntArray` previously using `instanceof` and that `o` must be at least an `IntArray` due to that and it defines a `myArray` field is not enough - you are required to cast it explictly:

```
((IntArray)o).myArray.length;
IntArray a = (IntArray)o;
a.myArray.length;
```

So basically that's it as far as that goes - you are not being explicit. I would have expected any syntax checking editor to have picked that up really so if that is approriate consider getting any one of the myriad available to avoid such mistakes.